# why i can not use map.entry<k,v> as a type in a clase heading, but can in a variable declacration

Tags: java

I was trying to write a treemap class, and I get a few problem, one of them with generic.
If java.util.Map.Entry is a type, that I can use in a instance declaration, why I can't use it in a class heading ?

why the generic work for this :

```
 public class test5 <K extends Comparable<K>,V>{

     TreeSet <java.util.Map.Entry<K,V>> treeBack;

 }
```

and not for this :

```
 public class test5 <java.util.Map.Entry<K,V>>{

 }
```

Comment: Does your IDE/compiler give you a hint?

Comment: What would the latter declaration mean in your opinion?

Comment: You can't use any real type in a class heading.  Only type _variables,_ though they're permitted to extend real types.

Comment: Because `java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>` isn't a valid type variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
 public class MyTest<K,V extends java.util.Map.Entry<K,V>> {

 }
```

Comment: And why do you think op means that, specifically?

Comment: Hmm, I would have said something like this: `public class test <K, V, E extends java.util.Map.Entry<K,V>>{
}`

Comment: Do you think OP wants V to extend `Map.Entry`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to extend Map.Entry somewhere? and want to define your class that way? you use class templates for genericizing your class.

for e.g

```
class GenericTreeMap<M extends Map.Entry> {
  TreeSet<M> treeBack;
}
```

Then you can do something like `GTM<CustomEntry> treeMap`, on the other hand if you just want to be able to use Map.Entry in your treemap implementation you don't even need to make a template.

```
class GenericTreeMap {
   TreeSet<Map.Entry> treeBack;
}
```

Comment: the question is more based on a general observation while doing an exercice who   asking to implement a treemap based on a treeset, who raised to me so much question, this is one of them. the question is : Write an implementation of the TreeMap class by storing a data member of type
TreeSet<Map.Entry<KeyType,ValueType>>.

Comment: so as i understand, using a type with generic as a type for a generic is not allowed ?

Comment: if so why declaring a new treeset with map.entry as a type work as in my original question ?

Comment: I don't follow you there. Map.Entry is not a generic, it is an interface defined with a generic key type K and a generic value type V and hence using Map.Entry inside `<>` at the class level doesn't make sense while you can use Map.Entry as a type inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

In your latter case, I think you mean something like this:

```
public class test5 <K, V, E extends java.util.Map.Entry<K,V>>{
    TreeSet<E> treeBack;
}
```

Generics are just as they sound, generic. Your generic variable cannot be a class itself, because that violates the intrinsic property of being generic: the class is not specified.

You *can* however, create a generic variable that **extends** a class, which in essence means your generic parameter can be any class that *extends* the class defined in the generic parameter.

Answer (score 0):

What is changing? Just the `K` and `V`? What does the Map.Entry have to do with anything. What about something like this? Then you can have the parameterized `Map.Entry`.

```
class Test<K,V>{
    TreeSet <java.util.Map.Entry<K,V>> treeBack;
}
```

In that case `K` and `V` are parameterized types. Perhaps you want Test to extend Map.Entry?

```
class Test<K, V> extends Map.Entry<K, V>
```

Now test is itself a Map entry.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply because it's not a valid type variable declaration.

Type variable declarations must be of the form

```
Identifier
Identifier extends ClassOrInterface
Identifier extends AnotherTypeVariable
```

Etc. (They can also have annotations, and other bits and bobs)

But the point is that they must start with an identifier. Java identifiers cannot contain periods, angle brackets etc.

So

```
class Foo<java>
```

Would be fine (if ill-advised), but

```
class Foo<java.util>
```

Would not work.